# I'm not receiving money from missions

Tags: payday-2

I just started the game, and completed 4 missions, but my spending cash is still the same.  I went to buy guns, and it says I still have same amount, even though last mission I earned $6000.  Where is my money going?

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade! When you post a question, be sure to use any appropriate tags. If your not sure, a hover over the tag badge will usually provide a pop-up with a brief description on its application.

In this case, I have suggested a change from the tag "glitch" to "payday-2". While your problem sounds like a bug, the tag "glitch" is actually for a game of the same name.

Answer (score 4):

First of all - most money ([80%](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Payday_(Gameplay))) you earn go into your "offshore account".

Disregarding that, there are a few things that will reduce your spending cash:

- Buying assets during the pre-planning phase
- Buying guns, attachments, masks, etc
- Spending skill points (Newer players often don't realise that this costs money as well as skill points)
- Accidentally (or otherwise) killing civilians incurs a fee that is taken directly from you spending cash

Side note: Completing one "day" of a mission and failing the next will not net you any cash.

If you didn't do any of the above, I can't say for sure what's going on. I'd recommend taking screenshots of your spending cash before and after a mission, as well as during the "Payday" screen, where money gets handed out. This way you can clearly see the difference and show or prove it when searching for help.